# What topological principle is at work here?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

[I'm [cross-posting this from MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4841720/what-topological-principle-is-at-work-here).  I initially asked there 10 days ago, and the question was well-received, but left unanswered.]

My question is inspired by a problem I discovered in *Putnam and Beyond*, #470, pg. 142:

> Does there exist a continuous function $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ that assumes every element of its range an even (finite) number of times?

The answer is yes, and they provide a caricature of a solution on pg. 542:

[image: Graph of solution.]

This solution consists of infinitely many linear segments in the neighborhood of 0.  One can prove that any solution must have infinitely many local extrema.

As I was thinking about this problem, I noticed that it depends delicately on the domain. If the domain were the circle $S^1$, then much simpler solutions exist, e.g. $e^{i\theta} \mapsto \cos(2\theta)$.

[image: Graph of easy solution for circle domain.]

Similarly, if the domain were a union of two disjoint intervals $[0,1]\cup [2,3]$, then $x\mapsto \left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2$ works.

[image: Easy solution for union of two closed intervals.]

If the domain were a single half-open interval $[0,1)$, then $\cos(4\pi x)$ works.

[image: Easy solution for half-open domain.]

**Question:  Is there a topological characterization of which domains admit "easy" solutions to this problem?**

Commentary:

- I leave open the question of what constitutes an "easy" solution, although I've noticed that "piecewise monotonic with finitely many monotone segments" suffices to distinguish all the examples above.
- My hazy intuition for this problem is that there is a sort of parity to 1D domains, with a closed interval having odd parity, a point having odd parity, a circle having even parity, unions have parity equal to the sum of the components, etc.
- I conjecture a generalization of this problem to higher dimensional spaces $X$ might be to consider maps $X\rightarrow X$ which hit each point in the domain an even number of times.

Comment: Your "parity" of a one-dimensional compact thing appears to be the mod $2$ Euler characteristic. 

Suppose that $X$ is compact and $f:X\to Y$ is a map such that each point of $Y$ is hit by an even number of points of $X$. Suppose also that $X$ and $Y$ admit cell structures such that each open cell of $X$ is mapped homeomorphically to some open cell of $Y$. Then each cell is hit by an even number of cells, so the Euler characteristic of $X$ must be even.

Comment: Your last bullet point (mapping $X\to X$ rather than $X\to [0,1]$) is a bit at odds with what you wrote before, and in fact this might be the more interesting version of the question: $S^1$ and a union of two intervals stop being "easy" if you map back to these spaces themselves rather than always $[0,1]$. (In the case of $X=[0,1]$, the issue disappears, because any continuous image of $X$ is a point or homeomorphic to $X$.)

Comment: @TomGoodwillie Nice, that seems to be the answer.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I'm not sure I follow you.  All the spaces in question contain an open subset homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, so the "easy" maps to $\mathbb{R}$ hitting each point an even number of times can be turned into similar maps into $S^1$ or whatever.  Right?

Comment: @Yly: I had surjective maps in mind.

Comment: I was thinking: zero is an even number, so never mind surjective. And to allow for higher-dimensional $X$, why not use maps into $\mathbb R^n$ instead of $\mathbb R$? Or of course any subspace of $\mathbb R^n$. What If $X$ is a locally nice (maybe triangulable) compact space whose Euler characteristic is even? Is there always a continuous map from $X$ to something also nice, such that each fiber has an even number of points?

Comment: @TomGoodwillie That's kind of what I was thinking with looking at maps $X\rightarrow X$, with the idea being that for e.g. a cell complex of dimension $n$, it contains an open set homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, so nice maps to the latter yield nice maps to $X$. I thought maybe the formulation just in terms of $X$ could be more natural, but perhaps that's a red herring. The trouble in either case seems to be identifying the right class of maps. Continuous is a bit too broad. Perhaps the smooth category is the right place to work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

EDIT: I've added an argument at the end that proves a more general statement and does so more simply.

I'll show that if $X$ is a finite simplicial complex having even Euler characteristic then there is a piecewise linear map from $X$ to a simplex (of the same dimension as $X$) such that the pre-image of each point has an even number of elements. In fact, the map will be simplicial with respect to the second barycentric subdivision $X''$.

(*) For any simplicial complex $Y$ of dimension $\le n$ we specify a simplicial map $Y'\to \Delta^n$ from the barycentric subdivision of $Y$ to the standard simplex by saying where the vertices go. We send the barycenter of any $p$-simplex to the $p$th vertex $v_p\in \Delta^n$ (and extend linearly over each simplex of $Y'$).

Of course, the vertex $v_p$ is hit an even number of times if $Y$ has an even number of $p$-simplices. I claim that if this is the case for all $p$ then every point is hit an even number of times.

To prove this claim, let $0\le p_0<\dots <p_m\le n$. Consider points in the interior of the $m$-dimensional face of $\Delta^n$ with vertices $v_{p_j}$. The size of the preimage of such a point is the number of $m$-simplices of $Y'$ that map onto that face. This is the number of "flags" $\sigma_0<\dots <\sigma_m$ in $Y$ where the dimension of $\sigma_j$ is $p_j$ for all $j$. This is divisible by the number of $p_m$-simplices.

In view of the claim, it now suffices to show that if the Euler characteristic of $X$ is even then $X'$ has an even number of simplices of each dimension (and then let $Y$ be $X'$).

In fact, if $p>0$ then the number of $p$-simplices of $X'$ is always even. For example, the number of $1$-simplices of $X'$ is the sum, over all $d$ and all $d$-dimensional simplices of $X$, of the number ($2^{d+1}-2$) of proper faces of a $d$-dimensional simplex.

Therefore the number of $0$-simplices of $X'$ always has the same parity as the Euler characteristic of $X$.

Conversely, if $X\to Z$ is a piecewise linear map such that each point is hit an even number of times then, choosing triangulations such that the map is simplicial, we find that $X$ has an even number of simplices in each dimension and therefore has even Euler characteristic.

EDIT: In fact, the following is true. For a compact PL space $X$ and an integer $k>0$, the following are equivalent. Let $c_p(K)$ be the number of simplices in a finite simplicial complex $K$.

1. $k$ divides the Euler characteristic $\chi(X)$.
2. For some triangulation $K$ within the PL structure of $X$, $k$ divides all of the numbers $c_p(K)$.
3. For some triangulation $K$ within the PL structure of $X$, there is a simplicial map $f:K\to L$ (for some simplicial complex $L$) such that the dimension of $f(\sigma)$ equals the dimension of $\sigma$ for every simplex $\sigma$ of $K$, and such that for each simplex $\tau\in L$ the number of $\sigma\in K$ such that $f(\sigma)=\tau$ is (finite and) divisible by $k$.
4. There exists a PL map $f:X\to Y$ (for some PL space $Y$) such that the preimage of each point is finite and has cardinality divisible by $k$.

Proof: 3 and 4 are equivalent, basically straight from the definitions.

2 clearly implies 1. To see that 1 implies 2, let $K'$ be the $k$-fold edgewise subdivision of $K$. Then $c_p(K')=k^pc_p(K)+\sum_{q>p}a_{p,q}c_q(K)$ for certain integers $a_{p,q}$. It follows that if $k$ divides $c_q(K)$ for all $q>p$ then $k$ divides $c_q(K')$ for all $q\le p$, as long as $p>0$. Therefore by repeatedly applying this subdivision operator we can arrange for $c_q(K)$ to be divisible by $k$ for all $q>0$. If also $k$ divides $\chi(X)$, then $k$ must divide $c_0(K)$ as well.

3 clearly implies 2. To see that 2 implies 3, use barycentric subdivision as in my original answer: If $K$ is such that $k$ divides $c_q(K)$ for all $q\ge 0$ then, letting $K'$ be the barycentric subdivision, the simplicial map $K'\to \Delta^n$ described in the paragraph marked (*) above satisfies the condition of 3.

Comment: I think it is true but not so obvious that if every vertex (in your context) has even fibre then every point has even fibre.  Perhaps you could spell that out a bit more?

Comment: @NeilStrickland: I've added some explanations.

Comment: Here's a more general fact. Suppose $k>0$. A finite simplicial complex $X$ has a PL map $X\to Y$ in which every fiber has cardinality divisible by $k$ if and only if $k$ divides the Euler characteristic $\chi(X)$.

The proof I am thinking of uses $k$-fold edgewise subdivision instead of barycentric. In the case $k=2$ it is maybe simpler than what I wrote.

Comment: Wow, with your observation about $k>2$, this circle of ideas is even more general than I had hoped for!  Very nice.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a sketch of this other argument.